# javascript - private/public members/functions

Tags: javascript

I am testing what happens when I declare variables/methods with var, this, and global, and am wondering what is the best approach. I have the following code:

```
myApp.ConfirmationWindow = function (temptype) {
    var _type = temptype;
    this.type = temptype;
    type2 = temptype;

    this.getType = function () {
        return _type;
    } 

    this.showConfirmationWindow = function (message) {
        var a = _type;  //valid
        var b = this.type; //valid
        var c = type2; // valid
        var d = this.getType(); // valid

        this.showWindow(message);
        showWindow2(message);
        showWindow3(message);
    }

    this.showWindow = function (message) {
      var a = _type;  //valid
      var b = this.type; //valid
      var c = type2; // valid  
      var d = this.getType(); // valid
  }

  showWindow2 = function (message) {
      var a = _type;  //valid
      var b = this.type; //invalid
      var c = type2; // valid
      var d = this.getType(); // invalid
  }

  var showWindow3 = function (message) {
      var a = _type;  //valid
      var b = this.type; //invalid
      var c = type2; // valid
      var d = this.getType(); // invalid
  }
};
```

Usage:
    myApp.ConfirmationWindow1 = new myApp.ConfirmationWindow(1);
    myApp.ConfirmationWindow1.showConfirmationWindow('Are you sure?');

The goal is to have the type variable and the showWindow function private. As you can see from my example, there are a lot of ways to achieve this. What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the module reveal pattern, where you keep the private variable in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Here below a generic example. You can read more about the [revealing pattern here](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript):

```js
let myVar = true;
let module = (function() {
  // these are private variables (in a closure)
  let _privateVariable = 'private',
      _privateFunction = function() {
          alert(_privateVariable);
      };
  let _publicVariable = 'public',
      _publicFunctionGet = function() {
          alert(_publicVariable);
      },
      _publicFunctionSet = function(value) {
         _publicVariable = value;
      };
  // provide public functions to set the private variables
  return {
      publicFunctionSet: _publicFunctionSet,
      publicFunctionGet: _publicFunctionGet
  };
})();

module.publicFunctionSet('new public');
module.publicFunctionGet();
alert(myVar); // available to other part of your code
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the module reveal pattern and the let syntax; I didn't know of either prior to this!

Comment: @user2769810 I am glad my answer like it, if you found my answer useful, please do not forget to click the upvote and approve my answer using the arrow up icon and tick on its left side. Thanks for your collaboration and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your private code using the var pattern in your example. To expose your private variables you use your instance functions. If you make them global or members of the function then they are public.

```
myApp.ConfirmationWindow = function (temptype) {
    var _type = temptype;
    this.getType = function () {
        return _type;
    } 
    var showWindow = function (message) {
      var d = _type
    }
    this.showConfirmationWindow = function (message) {
        showWindow(message);
    }  
};
```

Comment: So in other words, any member that is a var is private, and any member that uses this is public

Comment: @user2769810 it really depends of your code, I made an edit to my answer showing that a var/let could be not private and visible outside a function

Comment: It appears that the module reveal pattern is more readable, and more scalable than using professor Allman's pattern. In which cases would a person use either pattern?